# What's the meaning of "pool" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is a part of a discussion between two people on the topic of the acceptance of gays in society:

Person A:

> No problem with people doing whatever the f--k they want...but the whole marriage thing is a little iffy, but I dont care enough to want to stop them.

Person B:

> How is it iffy?!?

Person A:

> It's iffy because it opens the **pool** of false marriages for financial or other gain, such as citizenship, ect. like I said, i dont care enough to want to stop it, but from a governance point of view, it may cause expanded abuse. my argument has nothing to do with morality or whatever other "emotional" sentiments.

What's the meaning of *pool* mentioned in person A's remark? I've looked it up, but was unable to find a definition that's relevant to the context.

Comment: Is Person A a native speaker? Where did you read this? Is the lack of capitalization and misspelling of "etc." faithful to the original?

Comment: It's not at all a "standard" usage. But I see no reason to suppose the author isn't a native speaker (the opposite, in fact). It's reasonably comprehensible. I couldn't swear it would convey *exactly* what the author meant (he probably wasn't being *that* precise anyway), but I suspect an appropriate replacement there might well be [*can of worms*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/can+of+worms) (things he didn't want to bring into the debate, because they would just complicate the issue). It's just *pool = pot = container [full of unwanted stuff]*.

Comment: @Martha Yes it's the exact copy of the author's post, but I'm not quite sure whether or not he's a native speaker, it's from a forum thread discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Person A seems either to be confused or to be using poetic language, as the meaning is not clear in itself but seems to reference a number of meanings and idioms:

Merriam Webster gives the following definition of "[pool](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pooled?show=0&t=1392421565)":

> 3***pool*** noun:
>
> 4 a readily available supply: as
>
> [...]
>
> c :  a group of people available for some purpose

The meaning of "pooled resources" in definition 6 is related:

> 6 a group of journalists from usually several news organizations using
>   **pooled resources** (as television equipment) to produce shared coverage especially of events to which access is restricted

In 4, "pool" is used to describe the group, rather than the individuals (like water in a swimming pool). The idea of "pooled" in 6 is similar: resources have been collected together (again, think of water in a pool).

So it seems that Person A is wanting to refer to a collective group of people committing false marriage, but they may have mixed this up with the ideas of

> A
>
> [opening (oneself) up to (something)](http://www.thewellnesswarrior.com.au/2012/07/how-to-open-yourself-up-to-receiving-more-in-your-life/), meaning that you are making
>   yourself available for something to happen to you

and

> B a [blowing something (wide) open (or blowing the lid off
>   something](http://www.yourdictionary.com/blow-the-lid-off)), meaning to expose the truth of something (usually in
>   reference to something scandalous): "I want to blow the lid open on
>   false marriages" would mean they want to expose the people (or "pool"
>   of people) who are having false marriages.
>
> and/or b [opening a can of worms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/open+a+can+of+worms), meaning to create a situation
>   that will cause trouble or be unpleasant

I think ultimately they used "pool" to give a sense that the group of people doing this (or who would do this) is quite large, and/or that they are a collective - a group with the same ideas and principles rather than individuals, AND that marriages would be "opened up to" a situation in which they happen falsely (for financial gain, etc) and/or that gay marriage equality would be like "opening a can of worms", which would cause problems.